# Company webserver's name is the same as my LAN domain - how do I put this in DNS?

Tags: linux, dns

I have set up a DNS service on a Debian 11 server (BIND 9.16.33-Debian) for my company's LAN with the following (forward) zone file (`mycomp.com` isn't the real name, of course):

```
# cat forward.mycomp.com.db
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.mycomp.com. root.ns1.mycomp.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
;@      IN      NS      localhost.
;@      IN      A       127.0.0.1
;@      IN      AAAA    ::1

@ IN  NS  ns1.mycomp.com.
ns1 IN  A 192.168.50.9
www IN  A 77.66.11.123

bonsai  IN  A 192.168.50.149
...
```

All PCs point to the internal DNS:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search mycom.com
nameserver 192.168.50.9
```

The problem now is, that the company website is also called `mycomp.com` - I tried to include `www` in `forward.mycomp.com.db`, and it works, in the sense that it resolves to the right address, but `www.mycomp.com` is only an alias for `mycomp.com`, so I still can't reach the website from inside the LAN. I can see from my searches that I am sort of on the right track, but I think I need to point my browser to `mycomp.com`. However, including `mycomp.com` in the file above doesn't work, obviously; how do I fix this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using the same DNS name already used elsewhere?

Comment: @Peregrino69 Yes, lack of forward thinking, I assume. Regrettably, I now have to deal with it, and changing the names is not a popular option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including "mycomp.com" in the file *does* work, but the syntax rules of zone files must be followed. The entry needs to be named either `mycomp.com.` (the trailing dot is important) or `@` (like your SOA/NS records).

Just like your "www" entry automatically gets the zone name appended, the same happens to an entry named "mycomp.com" which is expanded to "mycomp.com.mycomp.com." in DNS:

```
www           A    77.66.11.123      ; becomes "www.mycomp.com."
sub.www       A    77.66.11.123      ; becomes "sub.www.mycomp.com."
mycomp.com    A    77.66.11.123      ; becomes "mycomp.com.mycomp.com."
```

To avoid this, the entry name must *already* have a trailing dot:

```
mycomp.com.   A    77.66.11.123      ; remains "mycomp.com."
```

You can also use the `@` shortcut to specify the zone root – which your SOA and NS records already have (and in fact you even have a *commented-out example* of it being used for A/AAAA records):

```
@         NS   ns1.mycomp.com.
@         A    77.66.11.123
```

---

The same automatic suffix is also applied to values, so it would be enough to write `NS ns1` – the server would automatically expand that to "ns1.mycomp.com." as well.

```
@         NS   ns1
ns1       A    192.168.50.9
```

Answer (score 2):

After the SOA record, you should write something like this:

```
@      IN      NS      ns1.mycomp.com.       # the final dot is NOT optional here.
@      IN      A       77.66.11.123
@      IN      AAAA    <mycomp.com web server IPv6 address>
@      IN      MX      1 smtp.mycomp.com.    # incoming mail server. Final dot needed.
ns1    IN      A       192.168.50.9
ns1    IN      AAAA    <DNS server IPv6 address>

bonsai IN      A       192.168.50.149
www    IN      CNAME   mycomp.com.
```

`@` at the left-most column refers to the "top of zone", i.e. `mycomp.com`.

Note the different record types: although a **NS record** of the `mycomp.com` top level needs to point to the DNS server, the **A record** for the same can point to the WWW server, and the **MX record** to the SMTP server. And since the NS record points to a **name** instead of an IP address, the nameserver doesn't have to have its own A record at the zone root.

The **CNAME record** defines `www.mycomp.com` as an alias of `mycomp.com`.